# HTML Element Collection filled from Previous Webpage Rather than Redirected Webpage VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, element, wait

The code below navigates to a webpage, fills search boxes with queries, and submits to the results page. However, the final element collection in the script, tdtags, which is defined after the redirect, is pulling data from the original search page, rather than the results page. I currently have the while ie.busy loop and a timed delay in the script, neither of which works. I have also tried waiting until an element only present in the results page becomes available in the html, but this also does not work.

```
Dim twb As Workbook
Dim ie As Object

Set twb = ThisWorkbook
twb.Activate

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
'church = Sheets("Control").Range("A2").Value
'minister = Sheets("Control").Range("A4").Value
location = "London" 'Sheets("Control").Range("A6").Value
'denomination = Sheets("Control").Range("A8").Value

With ie
.navigate "http://www.ukchurch.org/index.php"
.Visible = True
Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
End With
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

Set intags = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")

For Each intag In intags
If intag.getattribute("name") = "name" Then
If church <> "" Then
intag.Value = church
End If
ElseIf intag.getattribute("name") = "minister" Then
If minister <> "" Then
intag.Value = minister
End If
ElseIf intag.getattribute("name") = "location" Then
If location <> "" Then
intag.Value = location
End If
Else
End If
Next intag

Set dropopt = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("select")
For Each dropo In dropopt
If dropo.classname = "DenominationDropDown" Then
Set opttags = dropo.getelementsbytagname("option")
For Each opt In opttags
If opt.innertext = denomination Then
opt.Selected = True
End If
Next opt
End If
Next dropo

On Error Resume Next
For Each intag In intags
If intag.getattribute("src") = "images/ukchurch/button-go.jpg" Then
intag.Click
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
Exit For
End If
Next intag

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

Set tdtags = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("td")
For Each td In tdtags
If td.classname = "pText" Then
Debug.Print td.innertext
Debug.Print ie.locationURL
pagecount = Right(td.innertext, InStr(td.innertext, ":"))
End If
Next td
Debug.Print pagecount

End Sub
```

Any diagnosis would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automating IE is a pain, so avoid it.

The following function requests the results page directly.

```
Public Function GetSearchResult(Optional ByVal ResultPage As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal ChurchName As String = "", Optional ByVal Minister As String = "", Optional ByVal ChurchLocation As String = "", Optional ByVal Denomination As String = "") As Object
Dim Request As Object: Set Request = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
Dim Result As Object: Set Result = CreateObject("htmlfile")

Request.Open "POST", "http://www.ukchurch.org/searchresults1.php", False
Request.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Request.send IIf(ResultPage = 0, "", "page=" & ResultPage & "&") & "name=" & ChurchName & "&minister=" & Minister & "&location=" & ChurchLocation & "&denomination=" & Denomination

Result.body.innerHTML = Request.responseText

Set GetSearchResult = Result
End Function
```

An example which prints the contents of the `td` with classname `pText` inside the table containing the search results

```
Sub Main()
Dim Document As Object
Set Document = GetSearchResult(ChurchLocation:="London")
Dim ResultRows as Object
Dim ResultRow As Object
Set ResultRows = Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(8).getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each ResultRow in ResultRows
    If ResultRow.Classname = "pText" Then
        Debug.print ResultRow.innerText
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**Update**
You need to add a couple of References to your VBA project to make the following code work.

In the VBA Editor, Goto the Tools Menu, Click References and in the dialog that opens add a check next to the following two items: `Microsoft XML, v6.0` and `Microsoft HTML Object Library` (

```
Public Function GetChurchDetails(ByVal ChurchID As String) As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim Request As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim Result As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Request.Open "GET", "http://www.ukchurch.org/churchdetails.php?churchid=" & ChurchID, False
Request.send

Result.body.innerHTML = Request.responseText
Set GetChurchDetails = Result
End Function

Sub Main2()
Dim Document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim Church As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set Document = GetSearchResult(ChurchLocation:="London")
Dim ResultRows As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim ResultRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim ChurchID As String
'Set ResultRows = Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(8).getElementsByTagName("td")
' all result links on searchresults1.php have a classname of resultslink which makes getting them much easier
Set ResultRows = Document.getElementsByClassName("resultslink")
For Each ResultRow In ResultRows
    ChurchID = ResultRow.getAttribute("href")
    ChurchID = Mid(ChurchID, InStr(1, ChurchID, "=") + 1)
    Set Church = GetChurchDetails(ChurchID)
    ' code to read data from the page using Church as the Document
    ' eg: Church.getElemenetsByTagName("td").....
Next
End Sub
```

You only need to use the "post" mode when your submitting data, for everything else you can use "get"

Comment: how would I would I send post requests to the links in the results page? Need to pull detailed data from each result's own page.

Comment: @Abagnale I've added a bit of extra code that lets you get the church details